# Matplotlib and Dataframes: How do I put the Date on x-axis from the Date column in my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm learning how to use MatPlotLib for the first time.  I have a dataframe called "Temps" which has 3 columns: Date, Low, High.

The "Date" contains the date.  "Low" contains the low temperature of the day and "High" contains the high temp of the day.  There are 10 rows in Temps, one row for each of the last 10 days (with dates in the Date column).

I want to plot the high and low temperature as line graphs in the SAME PLOT, and my code for that part works:

```
Temps['High'].plot()
Temps['Low'].plot()
```

How do I add the Date to the X-axis so that I can see the High and Low temps on the Date that they occurred on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `Date`as index.

```
Temps = Temps.set_index('Date')
Temps['High'].plot()
Temps['Low'].plot()
```